# Edit Unit Price line item After Adding product to the cart

Tags: commerce

I am working with [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).

How I could edit the Unit Price of all Commerce Line Items to *$200* when "Add a Product to Cart" Event is fired. !

Answer (score 1):

this rule update unit price Unit Price of all Commerce Line Items to $200 when "Add a Product to Cart" Event is fired.

```
{ "rules_set_unit_price" : {
"LABEL" : "Set Unit Price",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_cart" ],
"ON" : { "commerce_cart_product_add" : [] },
"DO" : [
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-unit-price" ],
      "value" : { "value" : { "amount" : 20000, "currency_code" : "USD" } }
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already tried this , and it works fine for me , Thanks for your answers.

{ "rules_calp8" : {

```
"LABEL" : "Set Unit Price",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [
  "commerce_cart",
  "rules",
  "commerce_line_item",
  "commerce_product_reference"
],
"ON" : { "commerce_product_calculate_sell_price" : [] },
"IF" : [
  { "commerce_order_is_cart" : { "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-line-item:order" ] } },
  { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "commerce-line-item:order:uid" ], "value" : "1" } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "commerce_line_item_unit_price_amount" : {
      "commerce_line_item" : [ "commerce_line_item" ],
      "amount" : "20000.00",
      "component_name" : "base_price",
      "round_mode" : "1"
    }
  }
]
```

}
}